# water-damaged 3DS, some buttons are now non-functional, any ideas?

Tags: repair, keyboard

so about 3 months ago I got my [Nintendo 3DS](https://www.nintendo.com/3ds/) wet. I tore it down, cleaned it up with isopropyl alcohol (of highest possible purity) and let it dry off.

unfortunately for me, there are some buttons that are non-functional, these are HOME, SELECT, X. Y works with some input lag. as the PCB is designed, well, SMD way I can't figure out how I could possibly repair the device so it would work as intended. what's interesting and probably obvious, everytime after I clean the PCB with isopropyl alcohol, these buttons work but for a short period of time, then it's the same - they simply don't work. my guess is that isopropyl alcohol improves the conductance of (as I assume) rusty circut paths. I could kind of re-solder the paths by using high temperature, but I've got no idea what is the MAXIMUM temperature I could use for doing that (and that's because I don't know exact parameters of SMD elements that are put on the circuit board, e.g. maximum temperature that cap can be exposed to etc.).

so, have you got ANY knowledge in this field, or maybe any other ideas or experience in this field?

Answer (score 1):

My success on keyboards used liberal (half bottle) amounts of isoprop with drainage until solvent flux contaminants are dissolved and drained then vaccum & blow dry for 24hr ( or filtered compressed air )